# Wrong layout is used on AVD of WVGA854 and 160dpi

Tags: android, android-layout, android-virtual-device, hdpi, mdpi

There are two layouts: layout-sw480dp-hdpi and layout-sw480dp-mdpi
An AVD of WVGA854 and density 160dpi

On this AVD, my application always uses layout-sw480dp-hdpi, but not layout-sw480dp-mdpi. I think layout-sw480dp-mdpi should be used.

Comment: can we use 'layout-sw480dp-hdpi' like this? I heard only layout-sw480dp like this.

Comment: Yes, 'layout-sw480dp-hdpi' is a valid resource folder name. many qualifiers can be attached after layout according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: A WVGA854 AVD will be `-hdpi` by default. Are you sure that you overrode this in your AVD settings?

Comment: Yes, i have set the density 160dpi, but AVD still load the layout xml of -hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

try using a fixed resolution of 480x854 with the desired density instead of using a built in configuration of the WVGA854 .

the configuration of WVGA854 mean that it's hdpi , so maybe the AVD manager has conflicts.

Comment: I got the same result using a self-defined AVD of 480x854 and 160dpi.It seems that AVD prefer to use hdpi when resolution is 480x854